# creating a landfill

Tags: objects, workflow, geometry-nodes

I would like to create a large landfill in blender but I'm not quite sure how to go about it.
I would like to create something like this:

[image]

I have this low poly trash I have downloaded that I would like to be the trash within the landfill:
[image]

I have tried using the geometry node but I can't get it to look realistic. I am also working on a laptop so creating so many of these objects is causing my computer to slow down enormously. Does anyone know the best way to go about this whilst also keeping it fairly simple so my laptop can handle it?

Comment: Are you planning any close-ups or what is this going to be used for? You might not need to have a high-resolution landfill if nothing will interact with it as well.

Comment: @Luciano the establishing shot will just be a large overview but then I will cut to a close up shot of a bulldozer pushing some of the rubbish. However, I will do that on a separate document as it is too complicated to do it all in the same one. So in short, for what I am asking, no, it will not be a close up shot.

Comment: you could just use a photo that you put on a mesh and sculpt the mesh  to give it bumps, it will fake the dump

Comment: @moonboots, I need the objects in the wide shot to be the same as the objects in the next close up shot that will be using the trash I downloaded. Otherwise the shots will not look like they were at the same place.

Comment: @Gorgious, I need the objects in the wide shot to be the same as the objects in the next close up shot that will be using the trash I downloaded. Otherwise the shots will not look like they were at the same place.

Comment: maybe this helps you https://youtu.be/CQ9VmCN2EsE (at least it looks similar to image 1)

Comment: Particles might do what you need like in this answer - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44606/how-to-make-an-object-appear-to-be-buried-in-sand

Comment: Please be so kind and share your blend file so we can tinker further on this task specifically. As this question currently stands, it is difficult to impossible to find a solution here. Thank you!